# what is the Best way to use shared preferences between activities

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a user preference in my app, which gets used by different activities. I would like to know the best way to utilize those preferences between different activities in my App.

I have this idea to create a shared preference object from the main activity and from there send intents to the different activities to take actions. Would that work...?

Or just keep calling `getsharedpreferences()` from every activity..?

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sending shared preferences through intents seems overcomplicated. You could wrap the shared preferences with something like the below and call the methods directly from your activities:

```
public class Prefs {
    private static String MY_STRING_PREF = "mystringpref";
    private static String MY_INT_PREF = "myintpref";

    private static SharedPreferences getPrefs(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0);
    }

    public static String getMyStringPref(Context context) {
        return getPrefs(context).getString(MY_STRING_PREF, "default");
    }

    public static int getMyIntPref(Context context) {
        return getPrefs(context).getInt(MY_INT_PREF, 42);
    }

    public static void setMyStringPref(Context context, String value) {
        // perform validation etc..
        getPrefs(context).edit().putString(MY_STRING_PREF, value).commit();
    }

    public static void setMyIntPref(Context context, int value) {
        // perform validation etc..
        getPrefs(context).edit().putInt(MY_INT_PREF, value).commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm.. too many choices here. but actually my user preference contains checkboxes that performs action in a listview. so i might go with the suggestions here. only problem is that its populating from a customCursorAdapter, so jjst figuring out where to call it

Comment: yeah.. it works, would have really shot myself in the foot if i had gone through the intent route!

Comment: Have you faced a performance issue using this approach ? because I am using the same approach and I have performance issue but not sure if this approach is the cause of the problem

Comment: If you have a lot of prefs you will want to batch them. If you are targetting android 2.3 or newer you should probably use the non-blocking apply() method instead of commit() - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply().

Comment: Why don't you just declare the whole class as `static`?

Answer (score 8):

You can use this way and declare same variables with same name in all activites where you want to use.

```
  public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
  static SharedPreferences settings;
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
  int wordCount;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    editor = settings.edit();

    wordCount = settings.getInt("wordCount", 4); 

  }
```

Here initially wordCount will give 4; 
And when you edit wordCount and want to store again

```
  editor.putInt("wordCount", 6);
  editor.commit();
```

You have to declare this same variables in activities where you want to use shared preferences. And its better you call getSharedPreferences in every activity.

I don't think that passing that preference in intent will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course use shared preferences in your applications.

If you have more than a simple type than string or int, you can use a singleton or extends the application class which will be accessible by all activities of your application.
=> No disk access here. Simply kept in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice & easy solution in **Kotlin** – just **copy & paste** the code into a new `AppPreferences.kt` file and **follow the 4 TODO steps** outlined in the code:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import androidx.core.content.edit

object AppPreferences {
    private var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? = null

    // TODO step 1: call `AppPreferences.setup(applicationContext)` in your MainActivity's `onCreate` method
    fun setup(context: Context) {
        // TODO step 2: set your app name here
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("<YOUR_APP_NAME>.sharedprefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
    }

    // TODO step 4: replace these example attributes with your stored values
    var heightInCentimeters: Int?
        get() = Key.HEIGHT.getInt()
        set(value) = Key.HEIGHT.setInt(value)

    var birthdayInMilliseconds: Long?
        get() = Key.BIRTHDAY.getLong()
        set(value) = Key.BIRTHDAY.setLong(value)

    private enum class Key {
        HEIGHT, BIRTHDAY; // TODO step 3: replace these cases with your stored values keys

        fun getBoolean(): Boolean? = if (sharedPreferences!!.contains(name)) sharedPreferences!!.getBoolean(name, false) else null
        fun getFloat(): Float? = if (sharedPreferences!!.contains(name)) sharedPreferences!!.getFloat(name, 0f) else null
        fun getInt(): Int? = if (sharedPreferences!!.contains(name)) sharedPreferences!!.getInt(name, 0) else null
        fun getLong(): Long? = if (sharedPreferences!!.contains(name)) sharedPreferences!!.getLong(name, 0) else null
        fun getString(): String? = if (sharedPreferences!!.contains(name)) sharedPreferences!!.getString(name, "") else null

        fun setBoolean(value: Boolean?) = value?.let { sharedPreferences!!.edit { putBoolean(name, value) } } ?: remove()
        fun setFloat(value: Float?) = value?.let { sharedPreferences!!.edit { putFloat(name, value) } } ?: remove()
        fun setInt(value: Int?) = value?.let { sharedPreferences!!.edit { putInt(name, value) } } ?: remove()
        fun setLong(value: Long?) = value?.let { sharedPreferences!!.edit { putLong(name, value) } } ?: remove()
        fun setString(value: String?) = value?.let { sharedPreferences!!.edit { putString(name, value) } } ?: remove()

        fun remove() = sharedPreferences!!.edit { remove(name) }
    }
}
```

Comment: why you did not use `commit()` or `appyl()`?

Comment: @KuvonchbekYakubov Good question, I don't remember. It probably worked like this but maybe it's wrong? Feel free to report or provide a fixed version (e.g. via GitHub Gists) and I'll update my answer! :)