# How to handle ListView in this situation Android?

Tags: android

I ran into the situation that I need a way to edit the data of list-view item from another activity. I can handle the click event on each item, then edit it on the fly. However, I still prefer to handle all the editing in a separate activity. My listview item is customized from BaseAdapter. 
Here is my main page,
[image]

Each item within the `ListView`, contains two other `TextView`. When the I hit the menu setting, it will go to another activity where I can edit and update the information:
[image]

I'm currently having two solutions in mind. Either retrieving data from the previous activity and update the whole `ListView` (which I think it's kinda expensive in the case user just edit one item). Or I can just get rid of the `ListView` and create a bunch TextView in the xml, by doing this I can just reference to each `TextView` by their id.  So my question is, which way is preferred in this case? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ListView is displaying Email, Name, Headline, etc?  That should be a fixed XML layout with TextView entries, I think.  ListView is for variable numbers of elements.  You CAN implement it with a ListView, but I wouldn't.

However, your concern about updating the whole list being overkill, I wouldn't worry about that either.  You're talking about 7-10 fields.  The amount of time Android needs to run through its lifecycle and display everything will dwarf you updating a few fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SharedPreferences` for this. You can create a wrapper class through which you can access the preferences.Thats the usual way to go about solving these kind of problems. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051875/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-shared-preferences-between-activities/4051993#4051993) for details.

You can have it as a variable in your application class, so that you can access that in a global context.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `SharedPreferences` is actually what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Use text views instead. List View code has been optimized for large amounts of data only and not recommended for small data.