# Sharedpreferences doesn't work in onCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, showcaseview

I try to display a showcase view that pointing to a menu item, but this sharedpreference just save before my app closed, after i close my app and open again showcase view will appear again. how i can show the showcase view only for the very first time?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_contact, menu);

    pref = getSharedPreferences(String.valueOf(getApplicationContext()), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = pref.edit();
    if (pref.getBoolean("isFirstTime", true)) {   // default true for first time
        editor.putBoolean("isFirstTime", false).commit(); // update  so it will false ever after
        new Handler().postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mFancyShowCaseView = new FancyShowCaseView.Builder(ContactTabActivity.this)
                                .focusOn(findViewById(R.id.item_sync)) // ActionBar menu item id
                                .focusCircleRadiusFactor(1.5)
                                .focusBorderSize(15)
                                .focusBorderColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA64D"))
                                .customView(R.layout.case_view_sync, new OnViewInflateListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onViewInflated(@NonNull View view) {
                                        view.findViewById(R.id.btnOke).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                                mFancyShowCaseView.removeView();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }).closeOnTouch(false)
                                .build();
                        mFancyShowCaseView.show();
                    }
                }, 50
        );
    }
    editor.commit();
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Instead*  of

```
pref = getSharedPreferences(String.valueOf(getApplicationContext()), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Use

```
pref = getSharedPreferences("First_tym_check",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

This is because :-

`String.valueOf(getApplicationContext())` this string value is *not* **CONSTANT**

If you restart the app, you will notice the value will change significantly like for instance :-

- `(yourPackageName).@521c1`  , **Next time** ,
- `(yourPackageName).@631d1`  ,

> So, the string value is different *every* time .

Answer (score 0):

use below code. Use apply() instead commit() and getApplicationContext().getPackageName() instead getApplicationContext()

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_contact, menu);

pref = getSharedPreferences(String.valueOf(getApplicationContext().getPackageName()), 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if (pref.getBoolean("isFirstTime", true)) {   // default true for first time
    editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("isFirstTime", false).apply(); // update  so it will false ever after

    new Handler().postDelayed(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mFancyShowCaseView = new FancyShowCaseView.Builder(ContactTabActivity.this)
                            .focusOn(findViewById(R.id.item_sync)) // ActionBar menu item id
                            .focusCircleRadiusFactor(1.5)
                            .focusBorderSize(15)
                            .focusBorderColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA64D"))
                            .customView(R.layout.case_view_sync, new OnViewInflateListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onViewInflated(@NonNull View view) {
                                    view.findViewById(R.id.btnOke).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View view) {
                                            mFancyShowCaseView.removeView();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }).closeOnTouch(false)
                            .build();
                    mFancyShowCaseView.show();
                }
            }, 50
    );
}
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: apply is not the answer here !!

Answer (score 0):

Immediately your case values committed the sharedpreferences, Please refer this link : [what is the Best way to use shared preferences between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051875/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-shared-preferences-between-activities)